# Deploy docker container to production preserving mounted volumes

Tags: docker

In my dev machine I have app container with mounted code directory f.e -v /host/code:/app/code

What is the best practice of deploying such containers to production?
How should I pack this mount binding inside container in a way that in prod I would only execute "docker load"... and get everything work.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice is to use a data volume container (a container which is only `docker create`'d, not `docker run`, because it does not run any process)
See "[Creating and mounting a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)"

That way, you can easily export and deploy that container alongside the other instead of relying on a local host path which might not be available once on the production host.